# let $x$ be in finite group $G$ and let order of $x$ is $p$. If $h^{-1}xh = x^{10}$ for a finite group show that $p=3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ be  the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$ and x $\in$  G an element
>   of order $p$. Suppose $ h \in  G  $ is such that $h^{-1}xh = x^{10}$. Show that $p = 3$.

I cant solve this problem i think it should be solved without using any special theorem please firstly give me a hint .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extended hints/steps (may be you want to cover the screen and reveal this one line at a time?):

- Because $x$ and $x^{10}$ are conjugates, and thus have the same order, show that $\gcd(p,10)=1$.
- By Little Fermat $10^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$. Why does this imply that $x$ and $h^{p-1}$ commute?
- Let $q$ be the order of $h$. Why is $\gcd(q,p-1)=1$? Why does this imply that $h$ and $x$ commute?
- Show that $p\mid 9$.

Comment: unfortunately i can't see the last one p | 9 .Actually i can't see why we need order of h i think when i see this i will get the last item .

Comment: If $h$ and $x$ commute, then $hxh^{-1}=x$, so... In the third bullet use Bezout's identity and the fact that the set of integers $n$ such that $h^n$ commutes with $x$ form a subgroup of the additive group of integers.

Comment: Good! Well done @rmznyzgyr

Comment: I'm unable to get that $ \gcd (q,p-1) = 1$. I understood that $ 10^q \equiv 1 \pmod p $ and that $ 10^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p $. then from this, how does it follow that  $ \gcd (q,p-1) = 1$ ?

Comment: @VikrantDesai: The claim $\gcd(q,p-1)=1$ follows from the fact $p$ is the smallest prime factor of the order of the group.

Comment: Okay @JyrkiLahtonen. I was thinking that from those two congruences we've got, we get that $ < h > = < h^{p-1} >  $ which implies that $ \gcd (q,p-1) = 1 $. This assures that we can use $ h $ in place of $ h^{p-1} $ in the relation $ h^{-1}xh = x^{10} $.

Comment: I meant we can use $ h $ in place of $ h^{p-1} $ in the relation $ h^{p-1} x h^{-(p-1)} = x $ to get $ hxh^{-1} = h $. So am I wrong anywhere ?

Comment: @Error404, just because $h$ and $h^{p-1}$ generate the same group, doesn't mean they are the same, in fact, there are $\varphi(q)$ such distinct elements.